# How can I set the size of char [] with int

Tags: c, char, size, sizeof

I want to create a `char foo[]` and set the size wit an `int` but it dosn't work at all!

```
}else{
    int start = match[1].rm_so;
    int end = match[1].rm_eo;
    char value[end-start];
    ...
}
```

The size of `value` is always 0, why is that so?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `end-start` ?

Comment: And what are the values of `start` and `end`?

Comment: start is 13 and end is 49 that is not the problem

Comment: how are you calculating size of `value` ?

Comment: One more annoying question, are you sure you are using a C99 compliant compiler? One that accepts variable-length automatic arrays?

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include it?

Comment: What compiler are you using, and what arguments are you passing to the compiler? Make sure the compiler is C99 compliant (or C11), because prior to C99, VLA's weren't supported. Also tell us what warnings and/or errors you're getting when you try to compile this. double-check everything, because your code _should_ work just fine: [see example here](https://eval.in/191372)

Answer (score 3):

You should use malloc for that.

```
char *value = malloc( (end-start) * sizeof(char))
```

When using malloc, remember to free the memory when your are done using the array.

```
 free(value)
```

See more here if you need more information please : [C Dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Comment: You are probably right, but end and start could easily be macros.

Comment: Yeah but does it change anything? They are still integers values right?

Comment: In that case, they are constant values and then the original syntax is valid for any version of C. Strict C99 and above should also accept his syntax, even if they are volatile.

Comment: Ah yea, i see.. So we need the questioner to help us out here.

Comment: A better solution in this case is to use VLAs. Avoid malloc unless you absolutely must use it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are compiling your C code against the old C90 standard. In that standard, array sizes had to be a compile-time constant. In modern C, there is something called Variable Length Arrays (VLA), which allows you to declare arrays by using variables, as in your example.

Note that VLAs have to be declared at local scope, you cannot declare them at file scope ("global").

The best solution is therefore to get a modern compiler such as GCC, then compile it as standard C code: `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors`.